# view-models are singletons? or not?

Tags: aurelia

The Aurelia docs on the use of Containers is clear that "Each time the Router  navigates to a screen, it creates a child container to encapsulate all the resources related to that navigation event and then auto-registers the screen's view-model in that child container. As you know, auto-registration, by default, results in the view-model being registered as a singleton."

However, what I see in my application is that all view-model constructors are by default being being invoked whenever the associated view is activated.  This is not view-model "singleton" behavior as I understand it.

Can anyone explain what I'm not understanding here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand the effect of child containers on lifetime. When the router navigates, it creates a child container and it registers the screen's view model within that child container. It is a singleton, scoped to that child container, not at the application level. So, when that child container gets disposed (next time there is a navigation), all the singletons registered within it also get disposed.

If you want the view-model to "outlive" the navigation request cycle, you can use the `@singleton()` decorator.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that the child container was disposed on navigation.

Here is what the docs say about @singleton:  "_This decorator allows you to specify true  as an argument to indicate that the singleton should be registered not in the root container, but in the immediate container to which the initial request was issued._"

So it sounds like "true" will yield the already-default behavior for view-models that you've described, and "false", while unspecified in the doc, will perhaps force the view-model to be auto-registered (as a singleton) in the root container?